# What does דשלהי stand for?

Tags: acronyms

I've seen this mentioned in the context of tefillot (and shiurim as well).

What does דשלהי stand for:

For example:

---

> להחזיק ביד לומדי התורה ולחזק הני ברכי דרבנן דשלהי . . . נתינה זו הנזכרת בכתוב נוהגת לעולם, דאע"ג דאין מצות מחצית השקל בזה"ז, נותנים זכר למחצית השקל, ואע"ג דאין מקדש ואין קרבן לכפר, נותנים הצדקה לעניים, ולהחזקת הני ברכי דרבנן דשלהי, לחזק ידי עמלי תורה, שיוכלו להמשיך בעמלם על התורה ועל עבודת ה', ובזה מתכפרים. וכבר אמרו חז"ל במסכת מגילה ‏(יג, ב)‏, ...
>   ‏

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The word שלהי is a aramaic word, not an acronym. It means worn out, or at the end of.

See targum Onkelos in Bereishis 25 29, on the word עיף, he writes משלהי.

In Devarim 25 18, we find the same עיף=משלהי.

Back in Bereishis 47 13  on the words ותלה ארץ מצרים targum writes ואשתלהי עמא דערא. Rashi there comments it is an expression of עיפות, כתרגומו.

This expression in targum is quoted by Maharil in the likutim section #78 where he writes:

שילהי פירקין, אמר דרצה לומר שהיו עייפין בלימודו מראשו עד סופו כשהגיעו שם, דתרגום של עייף שילהי.

So the Talmud in Bava Metzia 64 & the Rishonim and Achronim had become accustomed to using this expression to indicate being worn out after having gone through something, like studying Torah.

It also indicates the end of something in general, but presumably for the same reason, as found in  Yevamos 115, Chulin 52. As found in the Aruch entry שלהי.

Answer (score 0):

knees bended from weakeness. as mentionned by cauthon.
see [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11566&st=&pgnum=1215&hilite=)
in hebrew ברכיים כושלות
D.D.
 שילהי is the end or the chapter. שלהי is weakness. As שהוא לאה in Hebrew. שילהי is similar to שוליים in Hebrew, "the bottom of" in English. The end is generally linked to weakness.

Comment: So שלהי פרק פלוני means the weak part of Chapter Whatever?

Comment: @msh210 שילהי is the end or the chapter. שלהי is weakness. as שהוא לאה in Hebrew. שילהי is simillary to שוליים in Hebrew, the bottom of in English